# Connect to Intersystems Cache DB via ODBC

Tags: database

I'm trying to connect to an external data source within out intranet site. The database is Intersystems Cache. Our web-servers are running Cent OS 6.4, so I have setup the necessary unixODBC drivers to connect to it and this is successfully working. What I'm struggling to work out is how I access this data from within Drupal.

I know I could just call odbc_connect within my code, but this isn't the Drupal way. I also loose the benefits of Memcached etc.

Would it be possible to use PDO's ODBC driver, which I think Drupal uses anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73914/msaccess-to-sqlite-install-of-drupal-and-setup-custom-content-types

Answer (score 1):

As @Bala said you want to try to install the PHP ODBC driver. Drupal does not use this driver by default (a drupal install may use MySQL, Postgres, or I believe MsSQL on install if those drivers are found by PHP).

Once the ODBC driver is installed for PDO, you can inform Drupal of your 2nd database by following the [Multiple Databases Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/18429). Bala linked you to a previous example I gave using ODBC to an MsAccess database file -- you're request is simply a different DBMS vendor. The same approach should work InterSystems Cache DB by following the concepts in the documentation page linked about.

Note that ODBC is a slow interface as its essentially a wrapper to your client Database. Its not as fast as a full native DBMS driver. Keep that in mind when querying and using your data.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I now successfully have PDO working with ODBC using native PHP, but I'm struggling to find the correct way of adding it to settings.php.
I have a DSN setup in odbc.ini so I can simply go $dbh = new PDO("odbc:CCMACDF"); and I'm connected. If I do the same in settings.php, only adding the driver = 'odbc:CCMACDF' key/value, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work" in drupal you would use `db_set_active('YourDatabaseKey for ODBC'); $result = db_query('select FOO;');` not `$dbh = new PDO(...);`. How to _select_ the database connection to use and issue a query is in the documentation link I provided.

Comment: The code posted above is showing the code used to test in native PHP to make sure PDO iss working outside Drupal. I use this within drupal: `db_set_active('CCMACDF'); db_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.iActivityCodeStat"); db_set_active();`. settings.php is `$databases['CCMACDF']['default'] = array(
 'driver' => 'odbc',
 'hostname' => '####',
 'namespace' => 'CCMA_STAT',
 'uid' => '####',
 'password' => '####',
);` but the error is `Failed opening required '/includes/database/odbc/database.inc'`